# Ionic promise inside a label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, promise

> This is a returned promise from an API, it accesses data and I am able to console log it inside the label, but how do I format it to output inside this Ionlabel/on the actual page not in the console?

```
     <IonList>

           <IonLabel>{
                postToAPI("ViewTransactions", [0]).then((result) => {
                 return ( <IonLabel>"+result[0]['TransactionAmount']+"</IonLabel>"); 
                })
           }</IonLabel>

 </IonList>
```

Comment: `const [myLabel, setMyLabel] = useState('');`

inside api response `setMyLabel(ReturnedLabel)`;

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib will this go inside the Ion label? can you provide some more context, as to where that piece of code should reside?